# como pegar um valor na tabela e soma com que entrar em php

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um sistema de conta bancaria e em um das operações o usuario tem que realizar deposito só que minha duvida esta já fiz o update da tabela que pega o valor que o usuário e altera na tabela mais como suma com o que tinha na tabela

ex

o usuário coloca 100$ mais na tabela tem 50 o saldo dele e pra ficar 150$

como e que posso fazer isso?

isso que já fiz [image: esse e meu banco]

```html
<?php include 'conecta.php';?>

 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Realizar Deposito</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
<?php
$idConta=$_POST['idConta'];
$valor=$_POST['valor'];

$sql="insert into trasacoes (idConta,valor) value ('$idConta','$valor')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

?>

<?php
$idConta=$_POST['idConta'];
$valor=$_POST['valor'];

$up = mysql_query("UPDATE conta SET saldo='$valor'  WHERE idConta=$idConta");



?>
```

Comment: primeiro vc precisa fazer um select antes....pegar o valor....somar e só depois gravar na tabela o valor atualizado

Comment: já fiz isso não deu certo

Comment: mas é assim q se faz. vc deve ter errado alguma coisa no seu codigo

Comment: <?php
$idConta=$_POST['idConta'];
$valor=$_POST['valor'];

$consu= mysql_query("select saldo from conta where  idConta=$idConta");

$atualizado = $consu + $valor;

$up = mysql_query("UPDATE conta SET saldo='$atualizado'  WHERE idConta=$idConta");



?>

Comment: faz um cast de float nos dois valores...e imprime o valor antes de atualizar no banco. checa se o tipo de campo no banco é varchar ou float...

Comment: **AVISO**: Esse código é vulnerável a [ataques de SQL Injection](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8677/137387).

Answer (score 0):

```
1 - select tabelaSaldoAtual ,
2 -  armazena na em uma variavel  ex: var saldoAtual
3 -  pega o valor que ele depositou e salva em outra variavel. ex: var deposito
4 - NovoSaldo = saldoAtual + deposito
5 - $up = mysql_query("UPDATE conta SET saldo='$NovoSaldo'  WHERE idConta=$idConta")
```

Comment: <?php
$idConta=$_POST['idConta'];
$valor=$_POST['valor'];

$consu= mysql_query("select saldo from conta where  idConta=$idConta");

$saldoatual = $consu + $valor;


$up = mysql_query("UPDATE conta SET saldo='$saldoatual'  WHERE idConta=$idConta");



?>

Comment: não deu certo !

Answer (score -3):

Eu faria dessa forma

```
$valorNovo = $_POST['valor']; //Isso deveria ser o seu input ou post que recebeu
$sql = "UPDATE conta SET saldo = ('$valorNovo' + saldo)  WHERE idConta='$idConta'";
$up = mysql_query($sql);
```

O update dessa forma vai somar o valor do Saldo atual + o $valornovo e esse método pode ser utilizado também para subtração de valores, porém que o POST ou INPUT deve vir com valor negativo.
PS: Sugestão como você está utilizando Mysql minha sugestão é que utilize o MySQLi do PHP [Clicando aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) você pode ir direto para o site do manual dele.